# get the texts with xpath query

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xpath, xpathquery

i want to get the main texts of this page :
[this link][1]
i used this code to find the main text :

```
NSString *tutorialsXpathQueryString = @"//div[@id='middlepane']/table[2]/tr/td/div[1]/font";
```

### but it is not working!

it is the saved page of that link

http://www.mediafire.com/?0t9de2f0b0928nk

@Ryan Kohn : no error happened
 and just returns empty or NULL value

that file is complex and large and i cant write in this page !

Comment: Instead of linking to the external site from here, please include a sample of the page's HTML that you wish to retrieve.

Comment: Also, are there any specific errors you're getting?

Comment: @coder4xc: Can you please provide the HTML code so that it might be easier to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this XPath:

```
string pageContentXPath = "//div[contains(@align, 'justify')]";
```

Note that this may be a bit unstable because it's using the 'align' property of the div.  If this changes, the XPath will not work anymore.

Comment: this does not work !  i want to get the texts of the font tag